# C++ Virtual destructors ROM usage

Tags: c++, oop, stm32, mcu

I try to understand why it takes so much code to create a base class with a virtual destructor.
I am getting ready to write a project on MCU with a small ROM space so it bothers me a lot.

```
#include "stm32g0xx.h"
#include "stm32g0xx_nucleo.h"

class test
{
    uint32_t data;
public:
    test(): data(0)
    {

    }
    ~test()
    {

    }
    uint32_t getData() const
    {
        return data;
    }
    void setData(uint32_t d)
    {
        data = d;
    }


};

int main(void)
{
    test t;
    for(;;);
}
```

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    936    1096    1096    3128     c38 Destructors.elf
```

```
#include "stm32g0xx.h"
#include "stm32g0xx_nucleo.h"

class test
{
    uint32_t data;
public:
    test(): data(0)
    {

    }
    virtual ~test()
    {

    }
    uint32_t getData() const
    {
        return data;
    }
    void setData(uint32_t d)
    {
        data = d;
    }


};

int main(void)
{
    test t;
    for(;;);
}
```

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3256    2144    1160    6560    19a0 Destructors.elf
```

Creating virtual destructor takes 2k of .text and 1k of .data memory... Why? Is it possible to avoid virtual destructor and still write safe OOP program?

Comment: Why are you asking us what's in your object file instead of disassembling it and looking at it yourself?

Comment: @Adrian which command you are using to get this information - 'text, data, bss, decay, hex'

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj arm-none-eabi-size "Destructors.elf"

Comment: Could you please check how the memory usage scales with increasing number of objects? Try with more objects of type `test` and also with some objects of a different class `test2`. Also try different optimization settings.